# The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected. Java home is different. Change Java Home

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

[Error Msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqLvv.png)

> "

The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
Java home is different.

Expecting: 'E:\Downloads\And_Std_2\android-studio-ide-173.4819257-windows32\android-studio\jre'
 but
 was: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181'.

Please configure the JDK to match the expected one.

> "

Android Studio was working well. It hanged suddenly. When I closed and Restarted it. The Error apparead.
 I have checked the path. It is same.
[jdk location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDOvt.png).
 But still error is not removing.
**Android Studio 3.1.3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but luckily I found a solution.

You have to set the JAVA_PATH variable like this.

**Step 1**

Windows 7 – Right click My Computer and select Properties > Advanced

Windows 8 – Go to Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings

Windows 10 – Search for Environment Variables then select Edit the system environment variables

**Step 2**

Click the Environment Variables button.

**Step 3**

Under System Variables, click New.

**Step 4**

In the Variable Name field, enter C:\android-studio\jre   (The path to the Java version that comes with Android Studio)

**Step 5**

Click OK and Apply Changes as prompted

**Step 6**

Restart your computer and it will work.

Comment: I have reinstalled my android studio. And its working fine now. I will try this solution if needed again. Btw thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

**MODIFY default Boot JDK**

1. **OPEN** the Action Dialog

[image]

2. **SEARCH** : switch boot jdk

[image]

3. **SELECT** the JDK installed by you rather than the intellij default

[image]

4. **RESTART** intellij idea
5. **IGNORE** this popup at right-bottom on IDE
   [image]

*HOPE this solution is work for you .*

Friendly link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/57193266/6897913